Enforcing consistent Schemas IDs across multiple environments via Schema Registry
We have a distributed system with multiple environments and have integrated a Schema Registry with some of our services. So far, we've created some tooling to aid in the migration of our schemas.
Since we are also using ksqlDB, we would very much prefer if schema IDs were consistent to avoid the cognitive overhead of creating tooling for a mapping layer between environments and schema IDs, which allows us to reuse ksqlDB queries consistently across all environments.
We have clear boundaries between prod/dev/etc on the network level (i.e. dev cannot directly interact with prod and vice-versa), so using a single global Schema Registry is not an option, and so this problem boils down to implementing some enforcement policy to keep schema IDs consistent across environments.
Our current favorite solution is to enforce identical schema IDs at the topic level. This essentially means that:

After doing required compatibility checks during pipelines/pull-requests/etc and testing, schemas are migrated/updated on our internal integration system. This is done via the Schema Registry API.
If everything checks out, we start a consumer group against the internal _schemas Topic of our integration system, one per target enviroment.
At an indeterminate time after the integration system is updated (but before compaction would trigger), we run our "schemas migrator" service which essentially replicates the _schemas Topic between the environments.

From what I can see:
The upside of this approach is that, as long as the consumers run before compaction triggers, we can safely and easily enforce consistent Schema IDs across all existing environments (new environment would have some manual overhead, but those would get added rarely enough that we're OK with not having tooling ready for that use case until we need it). In addition, since the original schemas are added via the Register Schema API, we shouldn't run into any trouble that would arise if we were plainly writing into the topic ourselves.
The only downside that I can see to this approach, is that we would be writing to the prod _schemas Topic directly via our custom migrator/replicator. Since the Schema Registry itself polls changes to the topic (for replication), this shouldn't be a problem in practice, and testing has so far shown it to work out of the box.
I'd love some input on this approach and whether there's something that I'm missing that would invalidate the approach.
